# How to remove the covariance of two measurement methods in order to separately estimate the variance of each

Tags: correlation, covariance, covariance-matrix, noise

I wish to compare two different methods of measuring an underlying property, and wish to extract the variance of each method of measurement, independent of the other.

The problem is how to correctly remove the covariance of two measurement methods that are applied on similar samples.

Let us assume that we are measuring the length of feet. People have left and right feet {L,R}, and I have two methods of measurement {a,b}, both applied to each foot, resulting in four measurements total per person {La,Lb,Ra,Rb}, each for N people measured.

The {L,R} measurements are expected to be highly correlated (most people wear the same size shoe on each foot), but the population of all people has a very wide range of foot lengths (shoe sizes range from small children to large adults). There is no a-priori reason to believe that left or right feet are systematically larger, or to believe that either of the measurement methods is systematically biased, so we can assume zero-mean, gaussian variation for the true underlying (L-R) measurement for each patient, and zero-mean, gaussian variation of any single observation of a measurement around the true value (i.e. mean(La-Ra)=0, mean(Lb-Rb)=0, mean(La-Lb)=0, mean(Ra-Rb)=0 and all of those have (possibly different) gaussian variances).

The objective is to estimate the variance of measurement method a (and b) as though we had been able to repeatedly measure a single foot from a single person many times over (in which case we would just calculate the variance of that single foot measurement). For technical reasons, in my actual application, that is not possible to do - but measuring two very closely related samples with both measurement techniques is possible.

The problem here is that the variance of each measurement method {a,b} is smaller than the true variance between {L,R} measurements. Therefore, if we simply calculate the variance of (La-Ra) and (Lb-Rb) over all patients, our variance estimates will be excessively high because of the underlying true variance of (L-R) measurements.

If we calculate the variance-covariance matrix, we could subtract the covariance from each variance, in order to calculate the variance contribution from each measurement method separately: var(a) = var(La-Ra)-cov(L,R). However, for any real set of measurements, there is a finite probability that cov(L-R) is in fact higher than var(La-Ra). The nonsensical result is that var(a) is negative, in other words our measurement technique has negative noise. There is also the possibility, when the true cov(L,R) is near zero, that the measured cov(L,R) is negative - which would imply that var(a)>var(La-Ra), again a physically nonsensical result.

I'm aware that to get var(a) from a calculation based on var(La-Ra), we will need to correct for the fact that we're summing two random variables with var(a) in them, e.g. var(a) = (var(La-Ra)-cov(L,R))/2 although I'm not sure exactly what correction factors to apply. I assume any calculation involving cov((La-Ra),(Lb-Rb)) should be similarly adjusted, but I'm also not quite sure how that would be done.

Inspired by the Neyman-Scott problem, I have tried changing my variance and covariance calculation denominators to account for fewer degrees of freedom, but basic simulations still show that it is easy to generate nonsensical results.

I have also tried to find analogous methods in other fields, for example I imagine that the noise on two microphones could be established independently, by comparing the samples of each microphone at neighboring time-points (i.e. this problem might possibly have solutions from sparse time-series analysis). No luck thus far.

Pseudocode:
To set up the toy problem assuming feet are 30+/-10cm long, with 5% left/right variation, and a true variance for our measurements of 0.5 and 1.0cm for methods A and B respectively:

```
True_Left = normal(mean=30,sd=10)
True_Right = True_Left * (1+normal(mean=0,sd=0.05))
La = True_Left + normal(mean=0,sd=0.5)
Lb = True_Left + normal(mean=0,sd=1.0)
Ra = True_Right + normal(mean=0,sd=0.5)
Rb = True_Right + normal(mean=0,sd=1.0)
Calculate La,Lb,Ra,Rb for 100 samples
```

var(La-Ra) = ~3 => sd(La-Ra) = ~1.7, which is ~3x higher than the sd(a) used of 0.5 in generation. We would expect it to be only sqrt(2)=1.4x higher due to the mixing of two random variables of normal(mean=0,sd(a)).

cov((La-Ra),(Lb-Rb)) = ~3, showing that the majority of var(La-Ra) is in fact from the underlying L-R variance, not from the measurement methods.

The problem is how to properly to correct for this, and extract an estimate for var(a).